# Cómo puedo instalar ggbiplot en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy tratando de instalar el ggbiplot para hacer un biplot estéticamente bueno. Tengo instalado el ggplot2 y el devtools. Cuando quiero incorporar el paquete de ggbiplot me sale el un mensaje de error diciendo que "no se encontró la función 'eval'":

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("vqv/ggbiplot", ref = "experimental")
Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@experimental
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/vqv/ggbiplot/zipball/experimental
Installing ggbiplot
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --
no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Victor  \
  Arce/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpC4F6Gj/devtools8385a7427b7/vqv-ggbiplot-
81e70b5"  \
  library="C:/Users/Victor Arce/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'ggbiplot' ...
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in eval(quote({ : no se pudo encontrar la función "eval"
Error : unable to load R code in package 'ggbiplot'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggbiplot'
* removing 'C:/Users/Victor Arce/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ggbiplot'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Alguno podrá ayudarme?

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Lucas, bienvenido a SOes. Ten en cuenta que este es un sitio en español. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla, de lo contrario podria terminar en espera o cerrada. Saludos!

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate the question.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección gente y perdonen, no me dí cuenta. Publiqué muy apurado. Ahora la traduje. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un [issue abierto](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/issues/29) en su repositorio sobre este tema, por el momento sigue abierto, aunque unos usuarios comparten una solución:

```
devtools::install_github("richardjtelford/ggbiplot", ref = "experimental")
```

En lugar de :

```
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot", ref = "experimental")
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente! Muchas gracias!

Comment: hola una pregunta me sale esste error Error: (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘Rcpp’ no se que hacer no puedo instalar el paquete